# missing files and lines after git merge

Tags: git, git-merge

I'm trying to perform a simple task : merging a branch into master but I can't get it working properly.
I do :

> git merge new-design

I have conflicts, no big deal, some files from my new-design branch are imported but a lot of them aren't, and some lines are even missing despite other parts of the file are already in conflict.

I'm not a great git user, I perform commits, pushs, pulls, branch switching and that's fine. All the ressources I read on the internet lead me nowhere

Comment: Maybe someone removed them in `new-design`?

Comment: No, when I switch on "new-design", I have all the files and the lines, nothing is missing

Comment: Git won't remove files unless they've been removed, or renamed, by someone. If I have file `a` in `master` and `b` in `test`, when I merge into `master` both of the files will be there.

Comment: Yes, that's what to be expected... but not what's happening...

Comment: That's not just expected, that's what will happen. If a git merge removes files then it's doing it for a reason.

Comment: obviously, that's why I'm asking here

Comment: You'll need to provide a concrete example where a file was removed for no apparent reason. It would be great if you could reduce and isolate it to a reproducible scenario. If you can't, at least post the history of one file from both branches. Asking in general terms won't work here, because in general terms, well, git doesn't remove a file for no apparent reason.

Comment: @evolutionxbox If you have file `a` in `master`, and `b` in `test`, and `master` used to have `b` but the commit introducing it was reverted - the result of the merge won't have both; only `a`.

Comment: @Gillespie a revert of an added file is a commit to delete the file

Comment: Right, but the commit to add the file might have been added to the branch accidentally, hence the revert. This is the most common scenario I've encountered. Accidentally commit a file to master. Revert. Commit file to branch A. Later when A is merged to master, file disappears because of revert commit on master.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently ran into an issue with very similar symptoms, and the root problem ended up being revert commits.

Say you accidentally committed some stuff on `master` that you meant to put on `new-design`. "No big deal" you think, "I'll just revert the bad commit(s) on master and repush to `new-design`". These revert commits have a subtle side effect though - the changes they contain take precedence over changes being introduced by a merge. So you might have conflicts where you didn't expect conflicts, missing code (because the lines/files were "deleted" in the revert commit(s)), etc.

The solution is simple: you have to revert the revert commits *before* `git merge new-design`.